# How to duplicate calculated fields while replacing the field from which they calculate in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop, calculated-field

I want to be able to take this calculated field (don't worry about the actual field)

COUNTD(IF [John Doe] THEN [response_id]
END)/COUNTD([response_id])

and create like 100 more calculated fields but [John Doe] will be replaced with the name of a different field. I'd like to do this in an automated way so that I don't have to manually create every single calculated field.

Comment: This sounds like you should be doing it a different way, like with a parameter or with one calculated field that has all of the conditions in it.  If, however, you want to generate your viz from code, your question will need more focus as this site is not intended to give tutorials.  You can not automatically generate calculated fields from within the Desktop app itself.

Comment: This would be easier if you reshaped (pivoted) your data - say to a tall thin version with columns like reponse_id and tag. You can automate the pivoting with either Tableau Desktop or Tableau Prep. Then you could have a single calculated field and apply to each tag.